# Python class definition assigning attributes

Tags: python

I tried executing this piece of code in my Idle and have the following error,

```
class Myclass():
    i = 1

x = Myclass()
x.y = 10
x.i=10
x.i
# 10
x.y
# 10
```

This class has only 1 attribute 'i', but when I assign x.y = 10, how will Python allow it to work. Isn't that a problem? How do I prevent it happening?

Comment: You come from a Java background, uh? **:D** Is not a bug... is a feature http://www.designer-daily.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/bug-feature.jpg

Comment: http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Comment: I think it's a very interesting question, though, specially, the *how to prevent* part... out of curiosity, mainly

Comment: Python lets consenting adults do that :) ...the only problem with your code is that your class should inherit from `object`

Comment: @Gerrat Actually, in most cases adding attributes outside of `__init__` *is* a problem, if only because you can never be sure what attributes a given object has (and thus, what is quacks like).

Comment: @delnan: I would say *some* rather than *most*.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Well, I won't start a fight over that. But I value the consistency afforded by not doing it, so I'm weary to do it unless there is a very good reason for it. And *very good* reasons (as opposed to "meh, won't hurt") are pretty rare in my experience.

Comment: @delnan... I'm with you here, man... errr... person (you never know)... I've suffered things like... seeing *if self.attrib:* with *attrib* not being in __init__ so... good luck trying to track where that attribute came from by reading 4 or 5 files of 4000 lines each... (Sorry for this irrelevant comment but I guess I got kind of traumatized with that and this helps me save a shrink)

Answer (score 4):

As other answers have mentioned, this is a feature not a bug.

If you want to enforce only a limited set of attributes, you can use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) with [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) (classes that inherit from `object`):

```
class Myclass(object):
    __slots__ = ['i']

>>> x = Myclass()
>>> x.i = 10
>>> x.y = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Myclass' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Comment: Is it a advantage or dis-advantage?

Comment: That's not the main intent to `__slots__` though (space savings are), and it comes with a whole lot of weird caveats. cf http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots

Comment: @user1050619 - That depends on how you look at it, it makes the language more flexible and allows you to write shorter code, but it can also potentially introduce some subtle bugs.  For example misspelling an attribute in compiled languages would probably be a compile-time error, but in Python you might not catch it until run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Python, unlike many other languages like Java, assigns class members dynamically. That means that you don't need to include a variable in the class's definition to be able to assign to it.

Also note that there is a difference between a class variable like the one you are assigning:

```
class Myclass():
     i = 1
```

and a class member:

```
class Myclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 1
```

Comment: Additionally, what you have written there is a class variable (like a static variable in java). Instance variables are defined inside `__init__`

Comment: This is misleading. Assignment at class scope has, in fact, nothing to do with object attributes - it's closer to static members.

Answer (score 0):

That is how you define class variables in Python. You could prevent this behaviour using some "magic" functions but that is generally not recommended.